# Каким способом можно отрисовывать призму в 3D?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, 3d

Каким способом можно отрисовывать призму в 3D? Так, чтобы при этом можно было программно изменять её высоту. С помощью каких библиотек лучше это делать?

P.S. Вынужден работать на Delphi 7.

Comment: Откуда у вас такое странное оторваное от контекста ТЗ?

Comment: Может, GLScene? http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/

Comment: @Kromster это лишь суть задания. А само - создать ёмкость с изменяемым уровнем жидкости

Comment: Зачем вам для этого аж целая библиотека? Почитайте теорию о том, как строить 3D проекцию на плоскость и нарисуйте этих пару линий самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов много, поэтому списком:

- Использовать GLScene (наверно самый дружелюбный вариант. Найдите схожий пример и допилите его под свои нужды),
- OpenGL/Direct3D/Vulkan - посложнее, но тоже можно найти и допилить пример (например, туториалы от NeHe),
- Самостоятельно задавать и переводить 3D объекты и рисовать их на 2D плоскости (велосипедное решение, но для 1 призмы может и лучшее).